# How to set default vim colorscheme

Tags: vim, color-scheme

The latest upgrade of Ubuntu made my vim colorscheme unusable. I know how to set it manually (`:colo evening`, for example), but I want to set the default for all vim sessions. I see reference in other places to `.vimrc`, but the right location and syntax have eluded me thus far.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Your `.vimrc` file goes in your `$HOME` directory.  In *nix, `cd ~; vim .vimrc`.  The commands in the `.vimrc` are the same as you type in ex-mode in vim, only without the leading colon, so `colo evening` would suffice.  Comments in the `.vimrc` are indicated with a leading double-quote.

To see an example vimrc, open `$VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim` from within vim

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
```

Comment: doesn't work https://github.com/ParamagicDev/vim-medic_chalk

Comment: if you want a colorscheme from a plugin, you’ll have to install the plugin first

Comment: I copy&paste from above GitHub link, https://imgur.com/LleDZUJ

Comment: @RYOENGLianHu Don't know what the problem is, you probably'd have better luck posting an issue on the theme's issue page on github or posting a new question here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 181):

Put a `colorscheme` directive in your `.vimrc` file, for example:

```
colorscheme morning
```

See here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_the_color_scheme

Answer (score 42):

It's as simple as adding a line to your `~/.vimrc`:

> colorscheme color_scheme_name

Answer (score 16):

You can try too to put this into your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
colorscheme Solarized
```

Comment: it should be
`colo solarized`

Comment: You can use either `colo` (the abbreviation) or `colorscheme` (the full term).  (For me `Solarized` and `solarized` are not recognized, but `default` and `koehler` is.)

Answer (score 15):

*What was asked for was to set:*

- *the '**default**', not some other color profile, and*
- *'for **all** vim sessions', not simply for the current user.*

*The default colorscheme, "for all vim sessions", is not set simply by adding a line to your  `~/.vimrc`, as all of the other answers here say, nor is the default set without the word 'default' being there.*

*So all of the other answers here, so far, get **both** of these wrong.   (lol, how did that happen?)*

---

**The correct answer is:**

Add a line to your system vim setup file in `/etc/vim/` that says

```
colorscheme default
```

or using the abbreviation

```
colo default
```

but not capitalized as

```
colo Default
```

*(I suggest using the full, un-abbreviated term 'colorscheme', so that when you look at this years later you'll be able to more easily figure out what that darn thing does.  I would also put a comment above it like `"Use default colors for vim"`.)*

---

**To append that correctly**, first look at your `/etc/vim/vimrc` file.

At the bottom of mine, I see these lines which include `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`:

```
" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

So you can append this line to either of these two files.

I think the best solution is to append your line to `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` like this:

> colorscheme default

---

**You can easily do that in bash with this line:**

```
$ echo -e "\"Use default colors for vim:\ncolorscheme default"  \
   |  sudo tee -a /etc/vim/vimrc.local

# 
#     NOTE:  This doesn't work:
#
#       $ sudo echo 'colorscheme default'  >> /etc/vim/vimrc.local
#
#     It's the same general idea, and simpler, but because sudo doesn't
#     know how to handle pipes, it fails with a `Permission denied` error.
```

Also check that you have permission to globally read this file:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/vim/vimrc.local
```

---

With `$ tail /etc/vim/vimrc.local` you should now see these lines:

```
"Use default colors for vim:
colorscheme default
```

Answer (score 9):

You can just use the one-liner

```
echo colorscheme koehler >> ~/.vimrc
```

and replace `koehler` with any other available colorscheme. Imho, all of them are better than default.

Comment: This will overwrite any existing configuration.  Maybe you mean `>>`?

Answer (score 6):

Once you’ve decided to change vim color scheme that you like, you’ll need to configure vim configuration file `~/.vimrc`.

For e.g. to use the `elflord` color scheme just add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` file:

`colo elflord`

For other names of color schemes you can look in `/usr/share/vim/vimNN/colors`
where NN - version of VIM.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 17.10 default doesn't have the `~/.vimrc` file, we need **create** it and put the setting `colorscheme color_scheme_name` in it.

By the way, `colorscheme desert` is good scheme to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Copy downloaded color schemes to `~/.vim/colors/Your_Color_Scheme`.

Then write

```
colo Your_Color_Scheme
```

or

```
colorscheme Your_Color_Scheme
```

into your `~/.vimrc`.

See this [link](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4417) for *holokai*

Answer (score -3):

OS:  Redhat enterprise edition

`colo schema_name` works fine if you are facing problems with colorscheme.

Comment: `:colo` is just the shorthand form of `:colorscheme`. This answer has been added four times already :-)