# How to change the default colorscheme in Vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I am using the default colorscheme in Gvim, but if there is any underscore in the document it shows red color as shown in following screenshot. Any suggestion to remove the red color will be kind appreciate. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Use the menu "Edit->Color Scheme" to change to an other colorscheme

Comment: @SebastianStigler: this will only change the colorscheme for the current session, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set default vim colorscheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975994/how-to-set-default-vim-colorscheme)

Comment: yes. But after you have decided which one you like you can add the `colorscheme xyz` to your `.vimrc` or `.gvimrc` to keep it as default.

Comment: I want to keep the default colorscheme since it comes with white background.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with the colorscheme; the red color is created by the syntax script (I suppose for `filetype=tex`), and it wants to alert you that you've committed a syntax error.

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; for your example, I get `texOnlyMath`.

There's a corresponding topic at `:help ft-tex-syntax`, under `:help tex-error`:

> ```
> Tex: Excessive Error Highlighting?
> The <tex.vim> supports lexical error checking of various sorts.  Thus,
> although the error checking is ofttimes very useful, it can indicate
> errors where none actually are.  If this proves to be a problem for you,
> you may put in your <.vimrc> the following statement: >
>         let g:tex_no_error=1
> and all error checking by <syntax/tex.vim> will be suppressed.
> ```

According to the `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim` script, the error also disappears if you

```
:let g:tex_no_math = 1
```

I'm not well versed enough in Tex to tell you which approach would be best for you; it's your decision.

Answer (score 0):

You change the default colorscheme to `darkblue2` by putting

```
colorscheme darkblue2
```

into your `.vimrc` (for Vim and GVim) or your `.gvimrc` for GVim only. [`:he vimrc`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#.vimrc) tells you where to place these files.

---

However, I think this is not your problem.
A colorscheme only tells how certain stuff is displayed:

```
hi Error gui=bold guifg=White guibg=Red
```

So, if the syntax file tells us that we're dealing with a syntax error, the `darkblue2` colorscheme will produce this as white text on red background.

Are you sure that the `_` characters are valid for your file type?

Comment: yes _ is the correct as I showed in the screenshot . I dont understandwhat do you mean by file type ?

Comment: @Raid: eckes is referring to TeX or LaTeX, in this context.  Vim detects the type of the file you are editing automatically, usually by file extension.